# Searching a list in Python for position of a certain word

Tags: python

So i have a string which i have split and from that created a list in Python.

I now need to find the location of a certain word in that list.

The problem that im having: the word im looking for appears twice in the list.  The code i have brings back the location of the first word however it doesnt continue and bring back the other location.

Example: The main reason that i play football is because i love football.

It will find the first FOOTBALL but not the second.  Help!!

This is the code i have :

```
sentence = " The main reson that i play football is because i love football"
sentence = sentence.split()

print(sentence.index("football"))
```

Comment: Please include your code with this question -- we can't help fix your code if we don't know what it's doing now.

Comment: Can you tell us what approaches you've tried that haven't worked?

Comment: Also, @DavidMašek, I have to disagree. For a simple task like this it would be much easier to iterate over a list of words than to use regex, unless you already have a lot of regex experience (which I don't have, and I assume OP doesn't either)

Comment: @DavidMašek - You are being sarcastic, right?

Comment: sentence = " The main reson that i play football is because i love football"
sentence = sentence.split()


print (sentence.index("football"))

Comment: @NcAdams I really misunderstood this question. Sorry to everyone. Already deleted the stupid comment.

Answer (score 2):

In the below snippet i will contain indices of 'football' in the list.

```
s = 'The main reason that i play football is because i love football.'
words = s.split()
i=[ind for ind,p in enumerate(words) if p=='football']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

looking_for = 'football'

in_text = 'The main reason that i play football is because i love football.'

without_punctuation = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z ]', '', in_text)
words = without_punctuation.split(' ')

for i, w in enumerate(words):
    if w == looking_for:
        print(i)
```

But of course. Punctuation is going to be an issue, like here (with 'football.') – so I've now stripped most of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def findall(list_in, search_str):
    output=[]
    last_index=0
    while True:
        try:
            find=list_in[last_index:].index(search_str)+last_index
            output.append(find)
            last_index= find+1;
        except:
            break
    return output
```

output is a list of the indices where search_str can be found in list_in